# Braintree payment integration : Using Client AuthorizationTokenization Keys

Tags: swift, paypal, payment, braintree

I am using Braintree payment in my app. It works perfectly fine using nonce method using server, [this](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v4) method. 
But now our requirements changed and we are not allow to use any sever to verify nonce.

In Braintree we can use tokenization key authorizes clients to tokenize payment information. But there is not any descriptive information about it, [this](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/authorization/tokenization-key/ios/v4) method. Only one line of code is provided in doc and there is no other resources I found useful for tokenization key method.

```
let apiClient = BTAPIClient(authorization: tokenizationKey)
```

How to use it with DropInUI ?

```
apiClient is always return nil.
```

Also I checked Briantreeios demo, but its very confusing. In some example I don't know how payment method work and on which end points used to verify details and deduct amount.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full disclosure, I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, I recommend contacting [Support](https://help.braintreepayments.com).

You are not able to perform transactions directly from the client. Braintree is a full stack solution that requires a server integration with one of [Braintree's available SDKs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server) or by using the [GraphQL API](http://graphql.braintreepayments.com). In either case, you cannot make payments directly from the client using a tokenization key.

Comment: Thanks for reply but this is not answer of my question, I want to know how to use tokenization key to do payment without using server and this answer is all about how to generate tokenization key.

Comment: My apologies, it sounded like your question was asking how to use tokenization keys to tokenize payment methods. I'll update my answer accordingly.